# Ruby deep nested hash from array

Tags: ruby, recursion

I need to convert this array:

```
[:a, :b, :c, :d, :e]
```

Into this hash:

```
{:a=>{:b=>{:c=>{:d=>:e}}}}
```

Unfortunately, I'm missing the Recursion Lobe of the brain.  I found [BottomlessHash](http://firedev.com/posts/2015/bottomless-ruby-hash/)

```rb
# http://firedev.com/posts/2015/bottomless-ruby-hash/
class BottomlessHash < Hash
  def initialize
    super &-> h, k { h[k] = self.class.new }
  end
end
```

While I'm struggling to understand the "[pretzel stab](http://symbolhound.com/?q=ruby+%26-%3E)", it does the trick if you write it out explicitly,

```
bhash = BottomlessHash.new
bhash[:a][:b][:c][:d] = :e 
bhash # => {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>{:d=>:e}}}}
```

However I can't figure out a way to pass arbitrary values programmatically.

`store` doesn't work, nor does `send("[:a][:b][:c][:d]=", :e)`

Comment: What should be the result if the array has 0 or 1 elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[:a, :b, :c, :d, :e].reverse_each.inject{|h, k| {k => h}}
# => {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>{:d=>:e}}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

What `send` does is call *a* method, just one, with zero or more arguments. It can't call multiple methods at once. Your example here:

```
send("[:a][:b][:c][:d]=", :e)
```

This is trying to call a method named, literally, `[:a][:b][:b][:d]=` which doesn't exist, so the `send` fails.

Now this bit of actual Ruby code:

```
x[:a][:b][:c][:d] = :e
```

Becomes interpreted by Ruby as:

```
x.send(:[], :a).send(:[], :b).send(:[], :c).send(:[]=, :d, :e)
```

Which is just a really long, ugly way of doing what the original code did. The key here is that each `[...]` part represents a method call that returns something and then the next part is evaluated against that, or *chained on*.

Now for the original part, this pretzel-stab:

```
super &-> h, k { h[k] = self.class.new }
```

The `&` means "pass through this Proc as a block argument", as in for a method with the signature:

```
initialize(&block)
```

Where `&block` represents a block, if given, to that method, as in:

```
Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = { } }
```

In a more basic implementation.

The `-> h, k { ... }` part is traditionally written as:

```
lambda { |h, k| ... }
```

Where that's probably more recognizable.

Answer (score 1):

```
items = [:a, :b, :c, :d, :e]

# Iterative version
def hashify(items)
  items = items.dup

  result = items.pop
  result = {items.pop => result} until items.empty?
  result
end

hashify(items) # => {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>{:d=>:e}}}}

# Recursive version
def hashify(items)
  return items.last if items.size < 2

  *head, penultimate, last = items
  hashify(head + [{penultimate => last}])
end

hashify(items) # => {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>{:d=>:e}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array = [*:a..:e]
array[0..-2].reverse.reduce(array[-1]) { |b, a| { a => b } }
#  {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>{:d=>:e}}}}
```